# request.url is not giving complete url in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running the following code snippet from the node js beginner book.

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");


function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log("request url issss " + request.url);
    var pathName = url.parse(request.url).pathName;
    console.log("Request for " + pathName + " received");

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello Worldd");
    response.end();

}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);  

console.log("Server has started11.");
```

Now while hitting `http://localhost:8888/start` in the browser, i am getting request.url is start only instead of full url. Hence path name is coming undefined.

Following is the console out put

Server has started11.
request url issss /start/
Request for undefined received

Thanks,
Shantanu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [`pathname`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url) with the `n` lowercased.

Also, `request.url` does not contain the fully qualified URL, it only contains the requested URL that the client sends.